# Estimating distribution parameter (lambda) from a poisson regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, glmm, poisson-regression

I'm running a `glmm` model with a poisson $(Poi\sim (\lambda))$ family. Now I need the value of the $\lambda$ to make the PIT histogram. I know that $\lambda = \exp\{X'\beta\}$, so in order to estimate this $\lambda$, should I make the mean of the $y_{fitted}$, given that $y$ is my response variable?

Comment: The exponentiated intercept coefficient from the intercept-only model will give you the grand mean, the MLE for $\lambda$ in a Poisson distribution.

Comment: My final model is using random effect, then should I use intercept-only model with random effect too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fit a mixed effects Poisson regression with the log link you define the model:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
Y_i \mid b_i \sim Poisson\{\lambda_i(b_i)\},\\
\log\{\lambda(b_i)\} = x_{ij}^\top \beta + z_{ij}^\top b_i,\\\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, D).
\end{array}
\right.$$

Note that the marginal distribution of $Y$ is not a Poisson distribution anymore. In the special case of a random-intercepts model, the marginal mean will be 
$$\exp \biggl ( \beta_0 + \frac{\sigma_b^2}{2} \biggr),$$
where $\sigma_b^2$ is the variance of the random intercepts, and $\beta_0$ the fixed effect intercept.